# How to create Dataset and fill the dataset in asp.net using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want fill the dataset in asp.net web application using Entity Framework. I am not familier with Entity Framework please help me.

How to create dataset and how to fill dataset?

Comment: The whole point of EF is that you **don't** have to deal with DataSet's rows/columns structure, but instead, you get nice .NET objects, properties populated, from your EF code...

Answer (score 5):

You do not usualy use `EF` to work with `DataSet` objects.

If you are interested in the standanrd way of populating `DataSet`, the following are some articles and tutorials that may help you working with `DataSet` objects:

[Working with Datasets in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[HOW TO: Create and Use a Typed DataSet by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714)

[Introduction to strongly Typed Data Sets](http://www.csharp-station.com/Articles/StronglyTypedDatasets.aspx)

[The C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson05.aspx)

If you are interested in working with *Entity Framework*, the following videos set may help:

[Practical Entity Framework for C#: Explore Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/Video/dd565857)

You can always use search engines to further searching for tutorials, guides and samples ..

Comment: And this is related to Entity Framework how? The original question was about filling data sets from Entity Framework...

Comment: @marc_s: OPs do not always know what they really needs .. I hope I've put him on the right direction.

Comment: I am  getting result using linq query.I want to bind  this linq query result  to  the dataset how can i  bind linq query result  to dataset?

Comment: @user737497: You dont need a `DataSet` to show the data on your _UI_ controls. Why do you want to use `DataSet` here?

Comment: I want Gridview sorting when i click tje gridview header text for that i want need dta set to assign the table to the dataview control

Answer (score 2):

you can populate your dataset with the following code snippests 
this question is already asked on stackoverflow.com and answered

you can find [Populate a DataSet using Context - Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626202/populate-a-dataset-using-context-entity-framework-4) here

so i just copy from there and paste here for you

```
     DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("myDataSet");
dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
//Setup the table columns.

foreach (CmsCategory categories in context.spCmsCategoriesReadHierarchy(n,sl,nn))
{
    DataRow row = dataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row["A"] = categories.A;
    row["B"] = categories.B;

    dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: **WHY** on earth would you want to do this?? You already **have** your nice .NET object - **WHY** kludge those back into a DataTable/DataRow schema??? That's like 20 steps back in time...

Comment: Why I need to use data set because I need sorting the grid when i click header text it should be in asc or desc if it is asc it should goes desc for that i need to use default view for grid  so i need to bind linq query result to the data set please help me.....

Comment: @user737497: you can achieve this by binding a `List<Customer>` directly to your grid - there's **absolutely** no need to convert back to a DataSet/DataTable just for this!! You need to read up more on Entity Framework and how to use it to databind to UI controls....

Comment: Ok... is it possible to assign the linq query to a data table

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Victor, From looking at the dates, I'm late to the party.  If you are reading this now, what these folks are trying to say is that you are mixing technologies unneccessarily.  The ADO.Net objects have essentially been replaced by the EntityFramework, beginning in .Net 3.5.

To answer the question posed on 6/25/2011, the actual code would be something like this:

List results = SomeQueryResults.ToList();

And that's about it.  Most of the rest of the work is done by the grid. you might have to override the OrderBy() function, but that might be it.