# Adding row to a datatable dynamically created from a class in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, grid

Hi i am new to C# and wondering if there is something that exists to simplify what i am trying to do.
I am using this sample to create a datatable from a class.
[Using Reflection to create a DataTable from a Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746064/using-reflection-to-create-a-datatable-from-a-class)

Question:

i would like to add rows to my datatable without individually populating each col.
How would you add a row to this datatable from an object?

Sample:

```
DataTable dogTable = CreateDataTable(typeof(Dog));
grid.datasource = dogTable;
...
private void populateData(Dog newDog)
{
   DataRow row;
   ...
   //How do i populate without without going through each field ?? possible ?
   //Since datatable was created from Dog there is a one to one relationship betwee
   //datatable and dog class.

   dogTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Is there an easy way to put newDog in the table ?

Comment: Read about Entity Framework - particularly Code First...

Comment: Why do you want to create a `DataTable` from a single object? That would always give a single `DataRow`. Or do you want to have a single `DataColumn` (f.e. `PropertyName`) and one row for each property?

Comment: maybe i didnt think this through. using the sample i am trying to create a table that contains columns that match properties of Dog. Object of Dog will then be each row in that table. Does that make sense ?