# How to use Entity framework to pass Table Valued parameter to Stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, table-valued-parameters

I have tables with 2 level hierarchy, Parent->Child->GrandChild
I have create stored procedure with three table valued input parameter ParentTable, ChildTable, GrandChild Table.

Now, I want to consume it in .net using entity framework.

Solution all over internet is, create DataTable in .net , store data in it and pass the same as parameter in stored procedure. 
But, I want to use entities instead of data table as data is stored in entity objects. Please suggest. Many Thanks.

Comment: It should be datatable, this is how ado.net understands it, but did you try to pass a list of entities? if yes, what error did you receive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746064/using-reflection-to-create-a-datatable-from-a-class) question

Create data table from entities and then pass it to the stored procedure. I haven't tried the code, just showing you the path to go. I hope it may help, looking for better solution.